# Self deletes shouldn't validate spam flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, deleted-questions, spam

Quite a few users are prone to flagging as spam any/all terrible questions, simply because they're terrible. This is incorrect use of the spam flag and if a moderator catches it the flags will be declined.

Unfortunately if the question gets deleted, including by the post owner, the flag gets dismissed as "helpful" automatically. It turns out too that many users are keen to delete their downvoted content - we even have a "peer pressure" badge to encourage it.

The side effect of all this though is that spam flags are getting incorrectly dismissed as helpful without any moderator seeing them ever. The most we can do on discovering this is dispute the spam flag, which also undeleted the self-deleted post and needs to be manually redeleted by a mod. (This has slightly different semantics too unfortunately)

I propose that self deleted posts with pending spam flags shouldn't cause the spam flag to be cleared either way. I don't think there's a case where self deleting ever should auto dismiss the spam flags as real spammers aren't exactly prone to deleting their handiwork and even if they did for some bizarre reason the  mod eyeballs could still be used to burn the whole account.

Comment: The real issue here is that there is a missing flag.  The community has already found a solution to that but it is not a well-known one.  Few new users know that they can visit the SOCVR room and ask for help.  Best solution is to incorporate what already happens in practice, a delete request flag and a review queue for it.  I'll use it myself, way too many vile Qs that I CV never gather enough votes.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think that participating a chat only to solve a (seemingly trivial) problem is too much hassle. When I see a bad post, I’m ready to help by flagging it. But I’m not going to join a chat, and discuss for several minutes to get the issue resolved. I understand that this is what mods do everyday, and I’m sincerely grateful that they donate their time for the good of the community. But for me, it is not an option. (NB: I’m not one of the serial spam-flaggers.)

Comment: This is something I asked for on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/dont-automatically-dismiss-spam-offensive-flags-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-the . In addition to validating bad flags, it also clears good flags and a delete / undelete cycle can prevent moderators from seeing spam or highly offensive content. I've seen spammers and trolls use this to dodge the notice of moderators.

Comment: I *have* to be missing something here but is there a reason downvoting terrible questions doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkB I kind of wonder the same thing sometimes.. like do we really have to close duplicates? To me the Q&A nature of the site might never make it really clean and perfect as a knowledge base... but it's still a pretty damn good knowledge base in spite of all the junk because the good stuff rises to the top, the bad stuff stays with few or no up-votes or even dipping into the negatives with down-votes. So I never felt so strongly about closing and flagging, even though I've been participating in SOCVR and trying to help out there a little bit (if only to understand the site dynamics better).

Comment: @MarkB The larger problem is people flagging bad answers when downvoting exists. Downvotes cost reputation, flags are free.

Comment: and flagging privileges can be lost, no? @Machavity

Comment: @MarkB I feel like the best thing closing and flagging does instead of down-voting is that it might help save the time of people who might have otherwise looked at the question to skip it. So it makes sense to keep the site clean for the newest questions in that case and try to direct the community's attention to more interesting and unique questions. It doesn't make as much sense from a posterity perspective since searches tend to give people what they want (provided they know how to do it) in spite of all the junk. But filtering the latest junk might save some time for answerers.

Comment: @MarkB flagging comes earlier than downvoting in the privileges roadmap. So users presume that the order is upvoting-flagging-downvoting. Maybe we should fix that by just making voting and flagging at the same rep level.

Comment: @Braiam the tricky thing with that is flagging is an important way for low rep users to get things undeleted when they've fixed a problem.

Comment: @Braiam I think users presume upvoting-flagging and never downvoting Answers because they themselves lose rep. Never take care of a mess at my own expense, that which someone else will endure at theirs. :P

Comment: @Flexo AFAIK you can always flag your own posts. This changed?

Comment: @Braiam not sure, I'm a little hazy around some of the low rep functionality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spam and offensive flags on a post will be preserved when the post's author deletes it starting with the next build (rev 2016.1.20.4108 on MSO/MSE, 2016.1.20.3201 elsewhere).