# Should I still flag question as spam even when it has been quickly deleted by OP

Tags: discussion, spam

Few weeks ago, I encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457134/unity3d-game-build) that was clearly spam. I was about to flag it as spam but some few other users did before I could do that but then *the OP quickly deleted the question*.

Does it really make sense to still flag the question as spam?

I am asking because I think that since OP deleted this question instead of a moderator, OP can still undelete that question again anytime. Also, is this thought correct? Can the OP still undelete this spam question again since OP deleted it?

[image]

Comment: That's *not* clearly spam. It's just wildly off-topic.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/dont-automatically-dismiss-spam-offensive-flags-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-the

Comment: Spam is a mass-noun. You cannot have "a spam". For what it's worth, I would have marked a spam flag helpful on that post, and so did the moderator who handled 3 spam flags on it. I shouldn't have to follow a link to a YouTube video just to confirm that it's *really* a video of Kevin Hart.

Comment: I absolutely believe that a spam penalty is reasonable there. There's no point in making it complicated. It's unsolicited promotion of some game and YouTube video having to do with Kevin Hart; that's spam. Why not assume the guy who posted links to Viagra wasn't just misguided about what is on-topic for our site? We get a lot of misguided users... Guessing about the motivations of spammers is neither interesting nor productive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a promotion stuff which I've seen many people try to do in the past with the unity3d tag in order to get more people download their app, expose their app to more people or make people visit their website. Plus, this user has never asked or answered a question since then so it looks like this account was created for stuff like this. They don't have to say "This is my/our app or website". They are getting smarter each day but you can tell by reading the way the question is asked. This is a complete spam: App link + App promotional video.

Comment: Bah, turns out I was wrong. I found a direct link between the poster and the company that makes that game. I'll not be duped again.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the question so that <10k users can understand what you're talking about?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Ccody Gray just did. By the way, any one know what happened to that account? It seems like it is now gone...

Comment: The account was destroyed by a moderator because its sole purpose was to post spam. So yes, it's now gone. You see an anonymized gravatar in place of the original user's information. Martijn's last comment is the hint about what happened. :-)

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but the completely unrelated title was an immediate red flag for me.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I noticed that too. The title was made so that it won't be flagged as a spam by others that would likely click on it just to flag it but the body is way off and has nothing to do with the title. That was another thing I suspected....

Comment: According to [Self deletes shouldn't validate spam flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315133/424903), should someone undelete their question the spam flags will be preserved. So at least that's something.